# Error! The requested URL returned 12030 - Unknown

Tags: jquery

I am trying to load a grid using Ajax call and also showing tooltip to the text in dropdown using the following Code

```
jq("select option").each(function () {
           jq(this).attr({ 'title': jq(this).html() });
     });
```

and in cshmtl using telerik grid i am binding the grid as below:

DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("GetEmployeeValues", "Account"))

Using Linq Query in Controller i am getting the Employee values and loading to the Grid.

The problem is when the place the tooltip related code in js i am getting error " Error! The requested URL returned 12030 - Unknown" and the Grid is not populating but dropdowns and tooltip are getting loaded but if i remove the tooltip related code i am not getting this error.
I am confused.

Awaiting for your reply!

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? Better still, maybe you should include the code for the AJAX-loading the grid.

Answer (score -1):

please use `Attribute [GridAction]`,and return new `GridModel`